# what is Luck in hinduism?

Tags: karma, teaching

I was randomly playing a video in youtube.The person said luck counts as a quality.I thought it is indeed so curious to know what is luck in hinduism.Is it result of previous karma?

Comment: Yes that is true.

Answer (score 2):

http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?tran_input=luck

The Sanskrit word for luck is अदृष्ट / Adrushta - meaning 'Not Seen'.

It's basically the consequences of your actions done long ago. If your actions were good, you'll get good luck, if not, bad luck.

If you go to work, you get salary - that is karma & phala.

But if you, say donate money to poor, there is no immediate benefit. But later in life, the benefit will come. By that time you would have forgotten the action which caused this benefit. So you call it 'luck'.

Comment: good explained but any scripture reference?